# Set of functions and surjective function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A,B,C$ be sets such that  $f:A\to B$ is a function.

Let $F: C^B \to C^A$ be a function, such that $F(k)=k\circ f$.

Prove/disprove that if $f$ is surjective then $F$ is surjective.

I tried to prove it: If $f$ is surjective so for every $b\in B$ there is $a\in A$ so $f(a)=b$, but what now?

Answer (score 3):

Leet $A=\{1,2\}$, $C=\{a,b\}$ and $B=\{1\}$. Consider the function $f:A \to 1$, which is constant and surjective.

Now, consider $g \in C^A$ given by $1 \mapsto a$ and $2 \mapsto b$. Clearly, there is no $h:B \to C$ so that $h \circ f=g$

---

Suppose that $f$ is *injective*.
Then let $g: A \to C$ be an arbitrary function. Clearly, we can construct the function $h:B \to C$ so that $h(b)=g(a)$ if $f(a)=b$, and arbitrary for every $b \in B$ so that $b \notin f(A)$.

By construction, it follows that $h \circ f=g$.

Comment: +1 because I like small examples that show the essence of what's going on. I would have been even happier if you had left $c$ out of $C$, making the example as small as possible.

Comment: @AndreasBlass your wish is my command

Answer (score 0):

It is false.

Let $A=C=\Bbb R$, $B=[0,\infty)$, $f(x)=x^2$ for $x\in A$.

Let $g:A\to C$ be defined as $g(x)= x^3$. Assume that there exists $h:B\to C$ such that $h\circ f=g$, that is $h(x^2)=x^3$. But this implies

$$h(1)=h(1^2)=1^3=1$$
$$h(1)=h((-1)^2)=(-1)^3=-1$$

But if $f$ is bijective then $F$ is surjective.

Comment: all you need is injective.